# Add Horizontal view to FullCalendar API

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

I am using full-calendar API for vertical resource view in my project. All is working fine for around 10 resources. But when I increase the number of resources in my project the view got screwed up.

[image: view with less resources]

[image: view with more resources]

SO how can I add a horizontal scrolling  in this view.

Comment: You need to adjust the bounding `div` to have its width be `auto` rather than `100%` or whatever it is now.

Answer (score 0):

in the viewRender callback function you can add something like

```
if(view.name === "agendaDay"){
        $('.fc-view-container').css('overflow-x','auto');
        $("#fullcalendar_container").css('min-width',$('.fc-resource-cell').length*slot_width_resource);
    }
```

I have my slot_width_resource equal to 125. You can play around with that value so the spacing works better.

Comment: Thanks Daffy can we fix the first column (time slots) on scrolling??

Comment: So when you scroll to far right the times stay on screen?

Comment: if so this is a bug basically tracking the issue you are having https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3022 it seems that it is not fixed but it has a css solution in it if you perfer that